# Whenever I try to run 1.7.10 in minecraft the game crashes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// You're mean.

Time: 4/8/19 3:39 PM
Description: Unexpected error

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1694)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1652)
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:125)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)
    at bao.p(SourceFile:1585)
    at bao.ak(SourceFile:774)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:728)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path, and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --

Stacktrace:
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:253)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1694)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1652)
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:125)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)

-- Affected level --

Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 0 total; []
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 0, 0
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (8,64,8), Chunk: (at 8,4,8 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 0 game time, 0 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 0 total; []
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Server type: Integrated singleplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at bjf.a(SourceFile:289)
    at bao.b(SourceFile:1972)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:742)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)

-- System Details --

Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 46900048 bytes (44 MB) / 201326592 bytes (192 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 12, tcache: 94, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.7.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.6.0 NVIDIA 419.67, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
Type: Client (map_client.txt)
Resource Packs: [vanilla]
Current Language: English (US)
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

So what's wrong with Minecraft? Why does it crash when I try to run 1.7.10?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the bug [MC-38527](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-38527), which is caused by downgrading a .minecraft folder (which is not officially supported). The fix, as given in the bug report, is:

> - Navigate to .minecraft
> - Open options.txt with an editor
> - Change the line renderDistance:XX to something like renderDistance:12
> - Save the file

Comment: it'd be great if i could see the bug report to verify this, but apparently bugs.mojang.com is down

Comment: Works for me. Either it's fixed now or it's an internet issue on your end.

Comment: yeah, it's working now.